# How to install dependencies on SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse, dependencies, suse, opensuse-12.2

I am trying to install TeamViewer on Suse.
My OS details are:

```
Linux wmiqgkt02 3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux),
```

but it is giving me the below missing dependencies.
How can I resolve that...

```
wmiqgkt02:~/Downloads # rpm -ivh teamviewer-suse_14.7.1965.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libQt5Qml.so.5()(64bit) >= 5.5 is needed by teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
    libQt5Quick.so.5()(64bit) >= 5.5 is needed by teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
    libQt5WebKit.so.5()(64bit) >= 5.5 is needed by teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
    libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5()(64bit) >= 5.5 is needed by teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
    libQtQuick5 >= 5.5 is needed by teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
    libqt5-qtquickcontrols >= 5.5 is needed by teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
    teamviewer conflicts with teamviewer-suse-14.7.1965-0.x86_64
```